# Removing page from notebook

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

So I'm trying to remove a page on a form ("Tickets" from an event).

Since it has an attribute "name" I thought I could just remove it by doing:

```
<page name="registrations" position="replace"/>
```

But I kept getting the message that it couldn't locate that name in the parent view.

So I tried using an xpath expr:

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[1]" position="replace"/>
```

And keep getting the same error, how can I remove a page from a notebook then? This is version 10.

Complete XML:

```
    <record id="event_add_weeks" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="event.view_event_form"/>
        <field name="model">event.event</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='registrations']" position="replace"/>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Please update your question with whole trace-back error message.

Comment: The complete xml record would be nice, too. Without this i would say that both replaces look just fine.

Comment: If using xpath this way (closing the tag right away) is not the problem, it could be that the page is not defined in the view. Let's say you have `view1` that does not have a page. `view2` inherits `view1` to add a page. You try to remove page by inheriting `view1` but you can't find the page there because `view1` does not have a page. Solution : inherit `view2` to delete the page.

Comment: @CZoellner added it

Comment: @Majikat I know how views work, this is not the case of wrong inheritance. This page does exist in the view in inheriting

Comment: Which Odoo version is used?

Comment: Do you have event_sale installed? That module is inheriting the same form view and is already replacing this `page`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<xpath expr="//page[@name='registrations']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

If not

```
<xpath expr="//page[@name='registrations']" position="replace">
</xpath>
```

Try this.

```
<xpath expr="//notebook" position="replace">
                       <page name="registrations" string="Registrations" invisible="1">
                            <group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="seats_min"/>
                                    <label for="seats_availability"/>
                                    <div>
                                        <field name="seats_availability" widget='radio'/>
                                        <span  attrs="{'invisible': [('seats_availability', '=', 'unlimited')]}" class="oe_read_only">
                                            to
                                        </span>
                                        <field name="seats_max" attrs="{'invisible': [('seats_availability', '=', 'unlimited')], 'required': [('seats_availability', '=', 'limited')]}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </group>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="auto_confirm" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
                                </group>
                            </group>
                        </page>
                        <page string="Email Schedule">
                            <group>
                                <field name="reply_to"/>
                            </group>
                            <field name="event_mail_ids">
                                <tree string="Email Schedule" editable="bottom">
                                    <field name="sequence" widget="handle"/>
                                    <field name="template_id" />
                                    <field name="interval_nbr" attrs="{'readonly':[('interval_unit','=','now')]}"/>
                                    <field name="interval_unit"/>
                                    <field name="interval_type"/>
                                    <field name="done"/>
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </page>

</xpath>
```

You may need to make the html invisible so that other dependent views do not fail.

Comment: Element '<xpath expr="//page[@name='registrations']">' cannot be located in parent view. Checked the view I'm inheriting from and it has the form with the name tough.

Comment: Oh, I think I know what to do. I will amend my suggestion

Comment: Can you tell if the error is being generated by your xml or another view that is trying to inherit the view? It is possible that another view tries to modify that page and because your xpath removed it it cant find it. Or maybe you need to target a different view id.

Comment: It is possible that another view tries to inject html using xpath into the same page and it is not your xpath that is causing the error. But after you remove the page the other views xpath now fails? Can you see if other views inherit this view as well?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the parent view uses that xpath itself and thus gives an error if you try to remove it. I'll check on it

Comment: Yes, this is why I changed my suggestion to simply add an invisible attribute. Please check by new answer.

Comment: It does not use that xpath. I've tried what you suggested before but it does nothing.

Comment: Marking the page as invisible still gives the same error?

Comment: It does not give an error, it just refuses to hide it for some reason

Comment: Alright, so find the view that contains the notebook. Copy the whole notebook so other view xpaths wont fail. Use the replace technique and dump the original notebook inside your replace. Add the invisible='1' tag to the page you are trying to hide.

Comment: Unfortunately, no success. Even went to the database and delete the form from ir.ui.view table, didn't work. I also used the Edit formview button on the form and manually edited the line to include invisible="1", again no success

Comment: This really should not happen. Are you sure you are updating your addon properly? Have you tried logging out and clearing your cache? Some UI changes dont occur until you have logged out and back in again.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked into the origin view of Odoo 8 `view_event_form`. You just have a typo, it should be "**R**egistrations". Following examples should work:

```xml
<page name="Registrations" position="replace" />
```

or

```xml
<xpath expr="//page[@name='Registrations']" position="replace" />
```

Comment: It's not a typo. I'm using version 10 and it's lower case there

Comment: Sorry, but this info was missing.

Comment: Man, I really do not know how I am going to sleep tonight if I cant make this page disappear. This is ruining my life! Joking, I updated my answer, try that. If it doesnt work. Please get a large object or a golf club or bat and proceed to smash your monitor while screaming like a lunatic. Hopefully your boss will give you stress leave and you wont have to explain why you cant hide this view.